# Flutter achieving ui/data synchrony

Tags: flutter

I have two screens:

1. Homefeed.dart
2. Profile.dart

On Homefeed screen all the data from various users is fetched from a server and is shown in a list of cards form.

On the Profile screen, only data that belongs to the logged in user is fetched.

The problem is that, there will be an overlap in the data that is fetched on the both the screens. For example if a user writes a post, it can show up on the Homefeed. Now if the user decides to perform any action such as like, delete, edit etc on thir post from the profile screen, then it should also update the same post that was fetched on the Homefeed screen.

Now unless user explictly refreshes the data, and send a request to server to fetch the updated data, what would be an ideal way to achieve this synchrony.

I did consider using a realtime database, but this will mean migrating current project and it might get expensive and might have problem of it own.

The other "hacky" way would be to maniuplate data somehow (I still havent figured it out) on the client side and show the update instead of fething new data from the server.

Or some other, more ideal way of achiving this, that I don't know of.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to reflect any changes of the user post i.e `edit`, `delete` in `Profile.dart` is by updating the database without tricking the just in the client side. Because you may reduce the database calls by tricking, but you are giving high chances of inconsistent data in database. Your database wouldn't be reliable.

###### Database should be the single source of truth

I would suggest, Every time `HomeFeed.dart` page is loaded , try loading the latest data from the `database`. If you are using real-time database, you dont have to check on every page load.